# How to delete pod from Kubernetes cluster using kubectl proxy

Tags: http, go, kubernetes, kubectl

I have this code that can get a list of pod running on the cluster by using **kubectl proxy** and the **http endpoint request**, I tried to look for a method that can delete a Pod from the cluster using the same way "**http endpoint request**", but I did not find how I can do that.

```
v := url.Values{}

v.Add("fieldSelector", "status.phase=Running")

request := &http.Request{
    Header: make(http.Header),
    Method: http.MethodGet,
    URL: &url.URL{
        Host:     apiHost,
        Path:     podsEndpoint,
        RawQuery: v.Encode(),
        Scheme:   "http",
    },
}
request.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json, */*")

resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&PodRunningList)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Comment: Isn't it just `Method: http.MethodDelete`? Why does [the actual go api](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/v10.0.0/kubernetes/typed/core/v1/pod.go#L153) not work for you?

Comment: thank you but I need to use  Method: http.MethodDelete ( I try it but it did not work , I think I need more detail about that  )